# Coding a triangle that incrementally increases

Tags: python

Ok so im pretty new to programming and im supposed to created a program that outputs the following using a nested loop

```
1)  1
2)  1, 2
3)  1, 2, 3
4)  1, 2, 3, 4
5)  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

so essentially the next number in the sequence is added every  iteration, so far i'v figured out how to get the numbers to the side to gradually increased using the code

```
for outer in range(1,6):
    print str(outer)+")",
```

iv tried just about everything but cant figure it out !

Comment: You done great till now , you need another for loop to write number themselves

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def triangle_printer(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print("%d ) %s" % (i, ", ".join(str(x) for x in range(1, i+1))))
```

Check it out:

```
triangle_printer(5)

1 ) 1
2 ) 1, 2
3 ) 1, 2, 3
4 ) 1, 2, 3, 4
5 ) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Using the `join` syntax helps you to print all of the numbers in a given range *on one line*, as opposed to having another `for` loop in which you first keep all of the numbers you want to print and *then* print them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it:

```
def triangle_print(height):
    sequence = range(1, height + 1)
    for unit in sequence:
        sequence_print = ', '.join(map(str, sequence[:unit]))
        print "{})  {}".format(unit, sequence_print)
```

Sample Output:

```
>>> triangle_print(5)
1)  1
2)  1, 2
3)  1, 2, 3
4)  1, 2, 3, 4
5)  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score -2):

just keep them in a list.

```
numbers = []

for number in range(6):
    numbers.append(number)
    print(numbers)
```